# Can AppEngine *pull* in data over 32MB?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm writing an API that needs to ingest HD videos (at least 100MB).  I only have access to the videos through an HTTP XML feed, so I can only *pull* the videos (with a GET) once I have the video's URL.  The plan is to store the videos in GCS.

But I'm running into the 32MB-per-request limit in AppEngine before I can upload/write to GCS.

Is there a GAE-way around these two limitations:

1. Needs to be a GET that AppEngine can initiate
2. Needs to be able to get the data into GCS

I know of Amazon S3, if I must go outside of Google Cloud products, but I don't know if that can be configured to pull in large data.

Thank you.

Comment: perhaps do a partial get, and write each block to GCS, then stitch them all together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following Paul Collingwood's advice, I came up with the following.

I decided not to write chunks to GCS and then stitch them back together.  Instead I chose to do it all in-memory, but I might change that depending on resource costs (had to run an F4@512MB to avoid exceeding an F2's 256MB soft limit).

```
def get(self):
    # Work with GAE's 32MB-per-request limit, set to 30MB to stay under
    RANGE = 30*(1024**2)

    url = self.request.get('url')
    request = urllib2.Request(url)

    request.get_method = lambda: 'HEAD'
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    info = response.info()
    logging.debug('Downloading {}B video'.format(info.get('Content-length')))

    request.get_method = lambda: 'GET'
    _buffer = ''
    start = 0
    while True:
        end = start + RANGE
        request.headers['Range'] = 'bytes={}-{}'.format(start, end)
        logging.debug('Buffering bytes {} to {}'.format(start, end))
        _bytes = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=60).read()
        _buffer += _bytes
        logging.info('Buffered bytes {} to {}'.format(start, end))

        # If there are less bytes than requested then all bytes
        # have been received, break to avoid an HTTP 416
        if len(_bytes) < (end - start):
            break

        start += (RANGE + 1)

    filename = '/MY-BUCKET/video/test_large.mp4'
    with gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='video/mp4') as f:
        f.write(_buffer)
    logging.info('Wrote {}B video to GCS'.format(len(_buffer)))
```

Which looks something like this in the logs:

```
DEBUG    2015-05-01 02:02:00,947 video.py:27] Buffering bytes 0 to 31457280
INFO     2015-05-01 02:02:11,625 video.py:30] Buffered bytes 0 to 31457280
DEBUG    2015-05-01 02:02:11,625 video.py:27] Buffering bytes 31457281 to 62914561
INFO     2015-05-01 02:02:22,768 video.py:30] Buffered bytes 31457281 to 62914561
DEBUG    2015-05-01 02:02:22,768 video.py:27] Buffering bytes 62914562 to 94371842
INFO     2015-05-01 02:02:32,920 video.py:30] Buffered bytes 62914562 to 94371842
...
Writing to GCS
...
INFO     2015-05-01 02:02:41,274 video.py:42] Wrote 89635441B video to GCS
```

**Update, 6/May/15**

Along the lines of Kekito's suggestion, I moved the GCS write into the loop, keeping the file handle open for the entire duration.

```
url = self.request.get('url')

request = urllib2.Request(url)
request.get_method = lambda: 'HEAD'
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
info = response.info()
content_length = int(info.get('Content-length'))
logging.debug('Downloading {}B video'.format(content_length))

del(info)
del(response)
del(request)

request = urllib2.Request(url)
start = 0
filename = '/MY-BUCKET/video/test_large.mp4'
f = gcs.open(filename, 'w', content_type='video/mp4')
while True:
    end = start + RANGE
    request.headers['Range'] = 'bytes={}-{}'.format(start, end)

    f.write(urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout=60).read())

    if end >= content_length:
        break

    start = end + 1

f.close()
```

Following the advice [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2008-January/483475.html), I used `top` to monitor the Python processes running the GAE local dev server, started an upload, and recorded the memory footprints between download-and-upload cycles.

I also experimented with changing how big a chunk is processed at a time: dropping the chunk size from 30 MB to 20 MB reduced the max memory usage by ~50 MB.  In the following chart a 560 MB file is being ingested, and I'm trying to track:

1. **GC**: the lowest memory usage, while `urlopen()` is **G**etting the **C**hunk of data
2. **WC**: the peak memory usage, while `f.write()` is **W**riting the **C**hunk to GCS

[image]

The 20-MB-Chunk-Test maxes out at 230 MB while the 30-MB-Chunk-Test maxes out at 281 MB.  So, I could run an instance at only 256 MB, but will probably feel better running at 512 MB.  I might also try a smaller chunk size.

Comment: I'm curious if you can avoid needing the larger instance if you write each chunk immediately to GCS (in the while loop) instead of writing them all at the end.

Comment: This is pretty cool. I wonder if you could do this in parallel? Once you have the length from the HEAD request you could start tasks in a queue and allow a couple of them in parallel. You might even combine with resumable uploads (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#resumable) so you wouldn't need to stitch the files at the end.